# Online simulations, games or ways to check my knowledge about traffic rules and my driving skills in USA

Tags: usa, driving, car-rentals, automobiles, traffic

I am looking to get a rental car in USA. I have a very good experience with driving a car but it is with right hand drive and in USA this is left hand drive plus the driving rules are somewhat opposite with my country.

Just need to know if there are any good online simulations or any other ways which can help me test my knowledge about my car driving skills and four wheel driving rules that are specific to USA where mostly the vehicles are left hand drive.

Also any important information related to driving rules like where to stop, when to change lanes and what are the do's and don't will be very helpful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 

Comment: You should try to get access to this simulator: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hesQ6ujrfqQ

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about driving skills

Comment: I disagree with this topic not being travel related. It is about preparing to travel to the US and is quite similar to http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/how-to-easily-switch-to-driving-on-the-other-side-of-the-road. With out the similator aspect it would be a duplicate, but it is clearly different

Comment: USA truck Simulator. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOYWE90mbyM There is also a Europe version for this, and as far as I know, they use the real road and routes.

Comment: Grand Theft Auto comes to mind...

Comment: @Dirty-flow I understand this may not be 100% related with the travel but I am clueless as to otherwise which stackexchange I should post this question. Already got a -15 for asking on meta.stackexchange.com whether I can repost it to stackoverflow.com. Please suggest, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Just checked its -40 as today :-( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187411/can-i-post-a-question-already-posted-on-travel-se-to-stack-overflow

Comment: @AnmolSaraf Consider this: you're going to an expert in Programming and asking him/her about the breakfast choices existing in the restaurant down the street from your house.  This is basically the same.  What I would suggest you do is read the [Help Page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help).  It's not surprising that you received this many downvotes and you will get more.  I would first look for services offered by driving schools around you in teaching driving on the right vs. left.

Comment: @Karlson Yeah I understand the down votes aren't wrong but I was just looking for a correct stackexchange site to post this question. I couldn't find a more suitable one than this and posted it here but did not receive any answers and was just not sure if I should post it to Stack Overflow as it has a bigger community, mistakenly in my anxiousness forgot it is for programming. I could have looked for services offered in USA but since I am new to this country, I don't know much and as a reason was looking for some online help from the Stack Exchange community.

Comment: @AnmolSaraf If you know where you will be staying you can easily find "driving school" near a location.  They can teach you the signs and give you actual driving experience.  But if you're looking for a game/simulator I'd start with the Game site: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=driving+simulator

Comment: @Karlson Thanks a lot for the above point. It is helpful.

Comment: Also note that driving laws vary from state to state, and unofficial rules of the road (notably the amount by which posted speed limits are exceeded) vary even more widely.